# What kind of graph is this?

Tags: graph-theory

I have drawn two graphs. The first is acyclic and directed and uses all the nodes. In the second I removed a node. Does the second graph have a name? Is it still directed and acyclic but with an additional designation? 
[image: You can see I'm not an artist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property that not all nodes are attached is called "disconnected". The first graph is a connected directed acyclic graph and the second is a disconnected graph with two components.

I suppose the second would still technically be directed and acyclic, but in my experience those terms are usually reserved for connected graphs.